# What do the word "takes to" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the definition of **[tense](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tense_(grammar))** from Simple English Wikipedia:

> *Tense* is the form of a verb that **takes to** show the time it happened.

What is the meaning of **take to** in this context?

Comment: Can you please provide a link: the Wikipedia page for "[tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tense)" is a disambiguation page.

Comment: @WeatherVane please search "tense grammar simple English Wikipedia". I'm having problems providing the link.

Comment: Oh, it looks like an error. I suggest it should read "Tense is the form that a verb  takes to show the time it happened."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error. The sentence should read:

> *Tense* is the form that a verb **takes** to show the time it happened.